# OCaml argument names

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

From a reading:

> Labels for arguments are often the same as the variable names for
>   them. OCaml provides a shorthand for this case. The following are
>   equivalent:
>
> ```
> let f ~name1:name2 ~name2:name2 = name1+name2
> let f ~name1 ~name2 = name1 + name2
> ```

When I put in the first line I get this error

```
Error: Unbound value name1
Hint: Did you mean name2?
```

I don't understand how they're equivalent if the first line isn't a valid function.

Comment: The variable `name1` in the RHS of `=` in your first line is not defined. I think this is a typo at ~name1:name2. The first line should be let f ~name1:name1 ~name2:name2 = name1+name2

Comment: It is from http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2015fa/l/02-fun/rec.html  .  If you have this course, you should ask TA fix it.

Comment: @TrungTa You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax of function arguments](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#argument) allows different expressions.

Given an expression `expr` that evaluates to a function `f`, the following syntax are allowed with the following rules:

- `expr arg` (given an expression `arg`): evaluate `arg` to a value `v`; the result is the value of `f` evaluated with argument `v`
- `expr ~lbl` (given a value *named* `lbl`): only when `f` has type `lbl:a -> b` for some types `a` and `b`, the result is the value of `f ~lbl` evaluated with argument `a`; OR, when `f` has type `?lbl:a -> b` (and then, `lbl` must have type `a` for typechecking).
- `expr ~lbl:arg` (given an expression `arg`): this is the same thing as `let lbl = arg in exp ~lbl` (except that the evaluation order of `expr` and `arg` is undefined).
- `expr ?lbl` (given a value *named* `lbl`): only when `f` has type `?lbl:a -> b` for some types `a` and `b`, the result is the value of `f ~lbl` evaluated with argument `a`; `lbl` must have type `a option` for typechecking.  This appears mostly when forwarding optional arguments from one function to another.
- `expr ?lbl:arg` (given an expression `arg`): this is the same thing as `let lbl = arg in exp ?lbl` (except that the evaluation order of `expr` and `arg` is undefined).